# How to update particular elements in a list?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
a = ["vishal", 123, 345, "out", 25, "going"] a[2] = 455 a[0] = "dinesh"
```

I expect the elements at index 0 and 2 are updated in the list, but instead I get a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 15, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your traceback is for line 15, showing that the line you show is not the entire snippet, so the cause of the error could be the previous line. Please show us a complete snippet that shows your error. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). BTW if you put semicolons between the three assignments there is no error in my Python 3.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write all the statements in the same line, it will be an invalid syntax.

For this, solution 1:

```
a=['vishal',123,345,'out',25,'going']
a[2]=455 
a[0]='dinesh'
```

Now print your list, you will see the result:

```
['dinesh', 123, 455, 'out', 25, 'going']
```

If you don't want to write in different lines, you can do this,
Solution 2:

```
a=['vishal', 123, 345, 'out', 25, 'going']; a[2] =455; a[0]='dinesh'
```

Use semi-colon between the statements, this makes the code run correctly.